# Take out sub set of indexes from array of type integer

Tags: java

So I have a List in which there are say 2 elements (suppose [1,2]), now the return type of method is int[] so I need to convert this Listto int[].

Here is my so far code,

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int lengthOfnums = nums.length;
    int[] indexOfNums = new int[nums.length];
    if(lengthOfnums != 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i <=lengthOfnums-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j =1; j<=lengthOfnums-1;j++)
            {
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] ==target)
                {
                   //l1.add(i);
                   //l1.add(j);
                    indexOfNums[i]=i;
                    indexOfNums[i+1]=j; // here somewhere logic goes boom


                }
            }

        }

    }
    return indexOfNums;
}
```

When I use (to operate on l1 arrayList)

```
Integer[] boxed = l1.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(Integer[]::new);
indexOfNums = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(boxed);
```

It gives output something like - [I@6bf2d08e, I think it is something related to address of memory, (not sure on this part).
So this one didn't work.

Also I can not use the for loop as I have to think about the complexity O(n) for my method.
Already complexity has reached to O(n)2 (square).

**What I want is **
if sum of two numbers is target then I want to get the index of those numbers.

Comment: No, I can not use for loop. If its possible. @MCEmperor

Comment: There are *many* possible solutions out there, including `list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()`. And using streams instead of a for loop won't change the complexity.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by converting the `Stream<Integer>` into a `IntStream` which has a `toArray()` method which generates an `int[]`

```
l1.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray()
```

Comment: If I use this, it gives 
indexOfNums =l1.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
                        System.out.println(indexOfNums); //[I@4cdf35a9 [I@4cdf35a9 - this is coming as output

Comment: @KavitaKulkarni But that's not because there's anything wrong with this answer; that's because you try to print an array directly. Try this instead: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexOfNums));`

Comment: yes, this works, but return type of method is int[]. So I can not write down return Arrays.toString(indexOfNums); @Jesper

Comment: Now you are changing the problem!  If your end goal is to produce a `String`, don't convert the `List` into an array.

Comment: And besides, there >>is<< an `Arrays.toString(int[])` overload.  Check the javadocs.

Comment: No, my requirement is to put the final answer in int[]. I am aware about the fact that if I want to produce a String, I wont need any conversion. I have updated my question with code. @StephenC